# The same image is not equal. Unit Testing. BitmapImage Property. C#

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, bitmapimage

Image Property:

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public BitmapImage Image 
   {
   get 
     {
       BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
       try
       {                        
         src.BeginInit();
         src.UriSource = new Uri(ReceivedNews.Image, UriKind.Absolute);
         src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
         src.EndInit();                        
        }
       catch { }
      return src;
      }
      private set { } 
    }
}
```

And the test method is:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanPropertyImage_StoresCorrectly()
{            
   string address = "http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/083/toy-car-red-1417351.jpg";
   var aSomeClass = new SomeClass(new News() { Image = address});
   BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
   try
     {
      src.BeginInit();
      src.UriSource = new Uri(address, UriKind.Absolute);
      src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
      src.EndInit();
     }
  catch { }
  Assert.AreEqual(src, aSomeClass.Image);
}
```

And I've caught an error in Unit Testing:

**Error in Assert.AreEqual. Expected: http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/083/toy-car-red-1417351.jpg. In fact: http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/083/toy-car-red-1417351.jpg.**

***I cannot really understand where the difference between the same images is? Why is it not approved by the test?***

Comment: Two BitmapImage instances won't compare equal, even if they were loaded from the same image file.

Comment: @Clemens please write your answer and I'll mark it. It is really just two objects and they are cannot be equal! Sorry for my absent-mindedness:).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two BitmapImage objects, even if created from the same image Uri, will not compare equal:

```
var imageUrl = "...";
var bi1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageUrl));
var bi2 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageUrl));

Assert.AreEqual(b1, b2); // will fail
```

However, you could compare their `UriSource` properties or their string representations:

```
Assert.AreEqual(b1.UriSource, b2.UriSource); // will succeed
Assert.AreEqual(b1.ToString(), b2.ToString()); // will succeed
```